# How to compare tabels and get difference out

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems to compare two of my tables. Usually I show my attempt how to solve a problem but here I do not know what to do. Normally, I do it in php. So i get all the information from 2 tables and then compare. But I would like to do it in MySQL. I hope you can help.

The first table, is my transactions table. This is the place where people have used their cards in restaurants.

The second table is my booking table. This is the place where people book reservations in restaurant.

I want to compare these tables, so i can get those who has NOT used their reservation

Transaction mySQL

```sql
SELECT t.*, em.* FROM transactions as t
  left join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
  left JOIN exp_member_data emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id ORDER BY t.created DESC
```

Transaction Table.

```
Trans_ID     TransactionTime         Name            Restaurant 
1852         2013-04-08 12:45:21     Christian       La Canton
1851         2013-04-08 12:41:00     Zaz             Parken
```

Booking mySQL

```sql
SELECT b.* from exp_menucard_booking as b;
```

Booking Table:

```
ID      BookingTime          Name            NumberOfPeople  Restaurant 
270     2013-04-09 14:45:00  Christian       2               La Canton
269     2013-04-08 12:17:00  Toby            4               La Raz
```

As you can se, Toby from Booking table has not used his card (transaction tabel). How can i get him out of my tabel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all persons, who have already booked (there is an entry in booking table) but do not have an entry in the Transaction Table you could try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Booking` B 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `Transaction` T 
    WHERE T.name = B.name
);
```

BTW it would be better, if you used some `User_ID` instead of `name` to identify the persons

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can select all the records that didn't use the booking. It's called an excluding left join or left exclude join. http://www.magecorner.com/mysql-joins-explained/

I'm not sure if this would be faster than WHERE NOT EXISTS, but considering that has a subquery, I think this is faster.

```
SELECT emb.*
FROM   exp_menucard_booking emb
LEFT JOIN transactions      t
  ON (
    t.Name       = emb.Name AND
    t.Restaurant = emb.Restaurant
  )
WHERE t.Trans_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM Transaction );
```